# Is it possible to make a website using GWT and JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, web

I'm going to work on a website with a few of my friends, but I don't really have much experience with JavaScript, HTML, or CSS. 
I looked at GWT and thought it'd be good for me since my best language is Java.

Most of the friends I'm working with, however, are familiar with web development in JavaScript and will likely use it on the project.

Is it possible for me to GWT to contribute and for them to use JavaScript on the same project?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. GWT generates Javascript blocks that are intended to be self-contained, and they don't readily interoperate with other Javascript libraries, even something as ubiquitous as jQuery. In my experience, with the exception of analytics and other aspect-type scripts, you're better off picking one approach or the other and using it for everything.

Comment: Agreed.  Google has stopped the use of GWT on a number of projects, presumably because of the lack of flexibility and bottlenecks.  You really need to learn JS, HTML, and CSS if you are going to be proficient at developing a web app, even if you use GWT.  You might as well do it right and leave the complexity of GWT out of the mix, IMO.

Comment: @MichaelMikowski I very strongly dislike Javascript and am not a fan of CSS, but I've come to the same conclusion and have spent the last few weeks learning enough to get the basics working enough for a prototype version. GWT is reasonably suitable for legacy-style business-oriented apps, but it's not what I'd hoped for for Web-style applications.

Comment: How long will it take to learn a sufficient amount of JS, HTML, CSS, and jQuery to the point where I can make decent websites if I'm currently experienced with mainly with Java, C++ and functional programming (in other words, with not that much web development experience)?

Comment: @kullalok Absolutely no way to answer that. It depends on what "decent" means, on what you're wanting the sites to do, and on how easily you pick the particular bits up. I do recommend starting at [http://webplatform.org], and keeping in mind that the core content of your site should be visible directly in the generated HTML so that search engines and other non-interactive browsers can index your content.